# Knockout.js web link RegEx

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm trying to validate web URL link in my application through Knockout.js. Because total form is done in Knockout.js I tried some RegEx but it's not done

```
<div class="input" data-bind="validationElement5: linkdocrequiredTextInput2, css: {'is-not-empty': linkdocrequiredTextInput2}">
    <input class="input-field" data-bind="textInput: linkdocrequiredTextInput2" id="linkdocurlInputTextId">
    self.linkdocrequiredTextInput2 = ko.observable().extend({ required: true })
</div>
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: By using regEx instead of writing code i want to validate web url or http links whenever user copy paste in the input box

Answer (score 0):

you can use following function on form submit to validate URL

```
  function validateURL(textval) {
    var urlregex = /^(https?|ftp):\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+(:[a-zA-Z0-9.&%$-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])){3}|([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.(com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|[a-zA-Z]{2}))(:[0-9]+)*(\/($|[a-zA-Z0-9.,?'\\+&%$#=~_-]+))*$/;
    return urlregex.test(textval);
}
```